# Error returned when calling Application.cfc method via Ajax (CF11)

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, application.cfc

I'm trying to test calling methods in a ColdFusion Application.cfc file using Ajax. As far as I can tell the following should work but I keep getting the following error returned:

"Invalid request of Application.cfm, Application.cfc, or OnRequestEnd.cfm file".

I am using ColdFusion 11.

The following is my Ajax call and the relevant method in the CFC.

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: 'GET',
  cache: false,
  url: 'Application.cfc?method=letsTestThis',
  success: function(response){ 
    alert(response);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error){
    alert(error);
  }
});  


<cfcomponent displayname="NAME" output="true" hint="Handle the application.">

  ... some more functions etc. ...

  <cffunction name="letsTestThis" access="public" returntype="string" output="false" description="">
    <cfreturn "It worked!">    
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly access Application.cfc from the URL.  Your ajax call needs to hit another CFC.  Also, access type of the method will need to be public.

Comment: So I need to create an intermediary CFC that I call using Ajax that calls the relevant function in my Application.cfc and passes the response back through to my Ajax function?

Comment: I have tested your solution and it is now working. It's now not really quite as useful as I was hoping for, however. Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to do something with onRequestStart or onRequest, check for URL.method, behave accordingly.  Your URL might be "approot/index.cfm?method=letsTestThis" or just "approot/?method=letsTestThis".  From there, you'd have to determine whether or not you want to actually call index.cfm.